# How to create a .jar file that actually runs?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, classnotfound

I am having lots of trouble with Creating a .jar file. every time i try to create one it, an error window pops up and says that the main class Start can not be found. (My main class is named Start) I have a manifest and everything can you tell me what i'm doing wrong please, or tell me what do do exactly? This can be from the command prompt or from eclipse as well!

Also sometimes a command prompt window pops up for a millisecond then closes in an instant!

My manifest says:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Start
```

My main class is Start.class

Comment: What's in your manifest, what's in your jar file (jar tvf), and what's the full name of the class with main() in it?

Comment: Are you taking into account your packages?

Comment: *"I have a manifest and everything"* Better than vague claims is a copy/pasted listing of the content (done by the Jar command).

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570845/java-eclipse-executable-jar-file

Comment: *"sometimes a command prompt window pops up for a millisecond then closes in an instant!"* Run the Jar from the command line using something like `>java -jar the.jar`.  It will still crash, but should dump the output to the console.  Copy/paste the output as an edit (along with the Jar structure).

Comment: Will you please stop editing the question so fast that you wipe out my edits?  I already fixed the manifest listing once!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my vague answer to your vague problem. It can be a variety of things. But the most probable one is than you have declared the Start class inside a package and didn't put the fully qualified class name in the manifest.

Assuming the package you have declared Start class in is `foo.bar.lazy` you need to give `Main-Class: foo.bar.lazy.Start`.

Comment: Where does the declaration start at? Do i do it like this? src.robert.Start?

Comment: On the top of your Start source file they'll be something like package foo.bar.lazy; you need to put whats there. Read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package for more information on packages.

Comment: I don't see anything called foo.bar.lazy! Is this supposed to be there in the manifest?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are joking, but... he didn't mean you should actually see foo.bar.lazy (heh) - you should see the fully qualified name of your main class.  Foo and bar are often used by programmers as class names to make points.