# Can someone help me help my computer find the main class in java?

Tags: java, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a .jar file that actually runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670767/how-to-create-a-jar-file-that-actually-runs)

The computer can't find the main class when I turn my classes into a jar file. I can run it from the command line but not by double clicking it! When i double click it, it says Can not find main class: robert.Start (Start is my main class!) Can someone help me please? I have a manifest file and everything and this is whats written in it

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: robert.Start
```

And my directories are like this:

inside the Interest.jar there is:

META-INF

robert

Inside robert are my classes

Can someone help me please? even when i don't create the manifest file manually it still does not run!

I am using windows 7.

I figured out the problem. It is when i run the program with jre7 it doesn't work. BUT with jre6 it works fine! I wonder why :/

Comment: Did you manually create that manifest file? If so, what operating system are you using?

Comment: Operating system?  How does that matter - this is Java, after all.

Comment: @duffymo It matters for the manifest file. The line terminators have to be exactly `\n`.

Comment: Ah, the manifest.  You're so right.

Comment: @Jeffrey  I prefer to leave the manifest to Ant or some other tool that understands how to make them correctly - including adding the 'completely blank last line'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I do too, but that doesn't mean the OP does

Comment: Yeah but I don't understand any of them!

Comment: So ***ask!***  There is no reason to believe you would understand the new answers given on a new thread, if you did not understand the earlier answers.  As it is you are wasting both your time **and** ours.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't package `robert.Start` correctly.

Open the JAR and look for `Start.class`.  When you find it, make sure that the path is `robert`.  If it's not, you have your answer.

CLASSPATH could an issue as well.  If you don't use the -cp option when you run, you'll have to have Class-Path set in the manifest as well.

Comment: I tried that too but it still does not work!

Comment: That line was generated when eclipse made the MANIFEST.MF file.

Comment: @Jeffrey No it doesn't, it tells the JVM where else to look for classes that aren't in this JAR.